# Einstein bot - Display Dynamic Options Name from Record

Tags: einstein, bots, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I'm trying to display accounts name from a list in a chatbot question, so the contact interacting with the einstein bot can select

The accounts are stored in a list Objects variable with the API name: "Accounts_Found_from_Contact"

[image: Dynamic Entries Configuration]

I tried to show the name of the account in the format formula field using both `{!Accounts_Found_from_Contact}` and `{!Accounts_Found_from_Contact.Name}`. But in both cases, while I was testing the bot display literally bot texts:

> {!Accounts_Found_from_Contact}

and

> {!Accounts_Found_from_Contact.Name}

How can I print the account names from those objects in the dynamic options?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the variable name from your apex class with `!`
For example if your apex class is :

```
public class ProductOutput {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public String ProductName;
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public String ProductId;
}
```

use `{!ProductName}`